# R Effective performance based method to fill a matrix without using nested for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, similarity

I have a DTM matrix with input data of 150 rows (actually even more huge >10000) to generate the similarity matrix output of dimensions 150 x 150.
Computing similarity where in the matrix should not be symmetric.
Cosine similarity is symmetric for A->B & B->A. (A & B represent the rows with text in dataframe).
Hence, I used a formula A/AUB.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(dtm))
 for(j in 1:nrow(dtm))
    mat[i,j] = ( rowsums(dtm[i,]) / length(names(which(dtm[i,]|dtm[j,]==TRUE))) )
```

With a sample of 150 rows for now (i.e. 150x150) the execution time are listed below
 - nested for-loop takes 16 secs
 - sapply takes 14.8 secs
 - outer takes 15.8 secs
 - for-each with 4 cores 13 secs

Even ~13-15 seconds for 150 rows of data execution time is too huge. for 500 rows it took approx 50 mins.
Is there any better approach to bring the execution to milli/micro seconds.?? Also suggest me any better approach to generate the non-symmetric similarity matrix very fast ??

Looking forward for early response.

Comment: If you have timings, where is the code that was timed? Could you please post it in the question?

Comment: Hi @RuiBarradas - the timings for one of them mentioned above with using for-loop is 16 sec. The code for others could not be disclosed at this moment due to certain reasons. but logic is same mentioned in the third line.

Comment: OK, another question: `rowsums(dtm[i,])` is the sum of **just one row**, the row `i`. Do you mean `sum(dtm[i, ])`?

Comment: Tips: 1) If you have `names` then your `dtm` is an object of class `data.frame`, much slower than a `matrix`. `dtm <- as.matrix(dtm)` should speed it up. 2) Your divisor can be `sum(dtm[i, ] | dtm[j, ])`. With a matrix 100x100 it took miliseconds.

Comment: Will consider your tip. for me it took 3 secs on 150x150. (Win10, 8GB RAM).   Any other suggestion or method to bring it to milliseconds ? because on 500x500 it takes ~9 mins

Comment: I had another question, in a previous comment. Is it `rowsums(dtm[i,])` or `sum(dtm[i, ])`? Anyway, from 16 to 3 secs is a speed up by a factor of 5+.